# Text with alternative definition of "derivative"?

Tags: calculus, reference-request, derivatives

Instantaneous rates of change are conventionally defined as limits of difference quotients.

Rates of things moving at constant speed are definable without delicate issues.  If I pass someone moving at constant speed at a particular point in time, it doesn't mean I'm going faster at that instant than he is; it might only mean that for a short time before and after that instant I'm going faster than he is.  But it does mean that that instant I'm not going more slowly than he is.  A similar criterion tells me I'm not going faster than some other, slower things moving at constant speed.  The boundary between those whose speed I do not exceed and those whose speed does not exceed mine is my speed at that instant.

More abstractly, if a line crosses a curve going from below it to above it as the independent variable increases, then at that point the curve is not steeper than the line; and similarly one can say that at that point the curve is not less steep than certain other lines.  The unique point on the boundary between those two sets of slopes is the slope of the curve at a point.

I recall that somebody mentioned this characterization of slope of a curve at a point on stackexchange within the past year.

Has a textbook been written that defines derivatives that way and gives proofs of the usual rule based on that definition?  If not, do those proofs appear in the literature or on the web or otherwise in public?

Comment: Isn't that definition going to run in to problems with things that aren't continuous over an interval such as $f(x) = \begin{cases} x^2 & x \in \mathbb Q \cr -x^2 & x \in \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q\end{cases}$ which is differentiable at $0$?

Comment: @kahen : What difficulties?  I think the definition I stated agrees that this particular function is differentiable at $0$ and its derivative at that point is $0$.  And if it didn't, I'm not sure that would be a problem.